# CHUNKING an audio signal with python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, audio-streaming, pyaudio

when i chunk an audio file (Sine wave in this case) the sound changes!

i want to stream out an audio signal (a sine wave). first of all i tried streaming the whole original Signal

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio as py
from scipy.io.wavfile import read


fs, y = read('Sinus_440Hz.wav')


p = py.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(y.dtype.itemsize),
                      channels=1,
                      rate=fs,
                      output=True,
                      frames_per_buffer=1024)

stream.write(y)              #Output 1 to 1 Original Sound  (WORKS FINE)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
py.terminate()
```

this works fine and i hear the original sine wave without any artefacts or modifications.

i need to treat the data in Chunks and then stream it out. i did it this way

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio as py
from scipy.io.wavfile import read

fs, y = read('Sinus_440Hz.wav')

totalSamps = len(y)
sample = 128
seg = 0

p = py.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(y.dtype.itemsize),
                      channels=1,
                      rate=fs,
                      output=True,
                      frames_per_buffer=1024)

while True:
     inds = 1 + np.mod((np.arange(sample) + sample * seg), totalSamps) # Chunks of 128
     Output = y[inds]
     stream.write(Output)    # Signal is not the same and have a lot of artefacts!!
     seg = seg + 1

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
py.terminate()
```

i didnt alter the signal yet and the sound of the sine wave has already changed

Why am i getting this signal changed although i didnt modifie anything yet? im just splitting it in Chunks
and stream it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to clean some things first, rename `sample` to `buffer_size`, then `Output = y[seg*buffer_size: (seg+1) *buffer_size]`